# How to merge changes from specific branch into different base branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-merge

I have a workflow where we have two branches `master` and `develop`. I checked out to `develop`, created new branch `feature1` and merged its changes to develop. Now after passing testing I want to merge my changes of ONLY `feature1` into `master` but when I set the base branch as `master` while merging `feature1`, it is trying to merge all commits of `develop` branch into `master` branch.

How can I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new branch from master, commit the changes you made, and then merge It to master. You May try to merge from a specific tag, but if you create a branch from develop, i think that all the commit you did, Will Be merged.

Comment: after creating new branch from master , how do I commit changes of feature1 to the newly created branch?

Comment: manually, usually. I don't know any other way, you can use some utility, like winMerge, for example.